# change attributes of the element in row jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I want to remove the disabled attribute of the text fields in a table when a user clicked the edit button from the selected row, but i don't know how I will filter the text fields that i want to change.

here is my php:

```
        $query_select = "SELECT `users_id`,`users_studno`,`users_fname`,`users_lname`,`users_email`,`users_password` FROM `tbl_usersinfo` LIMIT 20";
        if($run_query = mysqli_query($con,$query_select))
        {

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query))
            {
                $id_val = htmlentities($row['users_id']);
                $studno_val = htmlentities($row['users_studno']);
                $fname_val = htmlentities($row['users_fname']);
                $lname_val = htmlentities($row['users_lname']);
                $email_val = htmlentities($row['users_email']);
                $password_val = htmlentities($row['users_password']);

                echo "<tr class = 'special_rows'>";
                    echo "<td>"."<input type = 'checkbox' value = 'id_val' style = 'cursor:pointer; '>"."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$id_val."</td>";
                    echo "<td>"."<input type = 'text' value = '$studno_val' class = 'data_field' disabled>"."</td>";
                    echo "<td>"."<input type = 'text' value = '$fname_val' class = 'data_field' disabled>"."</td>";
                    echo "<td>"."<input type = 'text' value = '$lname_val' class = 'data_field' disabled>"."</td>";
                    echo "<td>"."<input type = 'text' value = '$email_val' class = 'data_field' disabled>"."</td>";
                    echo "<td>"."<input type = 'text' value = '$password_val' class = 'data_field' disabled>"."</td>";
                    echo "<td>"."<a style = 'cursor:pointer' class = 'edit'>edit</a> <a style = 'cursor:pointer' class = 'save'>delete</a>"."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
```

here is my jquery:

```
var edit = 0;
var save = false;

$('.edit').click(function()
{
    if( edit %2 == 0)
    {
        $('#tbl_users').find('tr').click( function(){
          alert('You clicked row '+ ($(this).index()) );
        $(this).index().$('.data_field').removeAttr('disabled');
        });
        $(this).text('save');

    }
    else
    {
        $(this).text('edit');
    }
    edit++;
});
```

example:
i clicked the edit button from the first row, all the first row textfields should remove all their disabled properties.

Comment: Why do you have spaces between the attributes and their respective attribute value in the HTML output?

Comment: I can't understand your question.

Comment: This `<input type = "text" ...>` should be `<input type="text" ...>`. It's good practice.

Comment: ohh, I always do that to make my code readable, but what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('.data_field', this).prop('disabled', false);
```

instead of:

```
$(this).index().$('.data_field').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code probably doesn't work because you are using removeAttr with disabled, which you should never do. Instead, use the `prop()` function.

According the [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), prop should always be used for setting disabled.

> Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value property of input elements, the disabled property of inputs and buttons, or the checked property of a checkbox. The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method. The .val() method should be used for getting and setting value.

Also, I'm not sure exactly what is going on here:

```
$(this).index().$('.data_field').removeAttr("disabled");
```

Instead, try this:

```
$('.edit').click(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").children(".data_field").prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Comment: @monkeycoder Sorry, I should have looked more closely. The click() function binds a new event. So, the find('tr').click(function... binds a new click event to the tr. I updated my answer to give you a better function. (Of course, add the edit % 2 stuff or whatever, but you get the idea)

Comment: Still not working, i tried this code: $('.data_field', this).prop('disabled', false); and works fine. thanks for the effort bro i'll give you +1